# Regex for matching the third,fourth,fifth... word

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings like `"aaa bbb ccc"`, `"aaa bbb ccc ddd`", `"aaa bbb ccc ddd eee`"....

I need a regex so that I can't get rid of `aaa bbb` and get everything else.

I'm trying `'\w+\s\w+\s(\w+|\s)+'` but it's not working.

```
In [171]: r = re.search('\w+\s\w+\s(\w+|\s)+', 'aaa bbb ccc ddd')

In [172]: r.group(0)
Out[172]: 'aaa bbb ccc ddd'

In [173]: r.group(1)
Out[173]: 'ddd'
```

I'd expect it to return `ccc ddd`

Comment: If the strings format is that definitive, why not just use str.split( ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method doesn't work because repeating capturing groups replaces the previous capture. If you make that a non-capturing group (including the quantifier) and wrap a capturing group around it, it should work.

```
re.compile(r"""
    (?:\w+\s){2}        # two words we don't care about
    (                   # begin capturing
      (?:\w+\s?)+       #   1+ word chars followed by an optional space, 1+ times
    )                   # stop capturing""", re.X)
```

Although I'm not sure why you're using regular expressions for this. Isn't `str.split` better?

```
s = 'aaa bbb ccc ddd'
result = s.split()[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you have not told the regular expression that the group should encompass all the repeats of `\w+|\s` ... as your `+` is outside of the parentheses.

Instead, try:

```
>>> r = re.search('\w+\s\w+\s((?:\w+|\s)+)', 'aaa bbb ccc ddd')
>>> r.group(1)
>>> 'ccc ddd'
```

Note that in this expression, the `(?: ...)` are *non-capturing parentheses*